# Woo commerce - variable product prices missing from WP

Tags: wordpress, variables, woocommerce, price

hoping for some help. 
We use the following - Wordpress/ woo commerce /wcvendors pro. Prices for variable products are disappearing from wp engine view despite being in the product variation information. It doesn't impact every product on our site but a fair few. How it occurs is, the price is disappearing when you go in and edit the product. If we quick edit the product the price reappears. But it will dissapears again if we use the edit button. Initially the problem started because under the  "Products" and "Inventory" We had checked the following setting: "Hide out of stock items from the catalog". Now this button is not ticked but it is still causing us issues.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an error on the product page which cause the price not to be saved.

There can be some reasons, here are two I see occasioanlly:

1. PHP error is caused during the save, and therefore the data is lost. WordPress and WooCommerce works flawlessly together, so the first suspects are other plugins and your theme. Try first to turn off all your plugins and switch to another theme to see if this happens again. If not try to activate your theme, and recheck, and then the plugins one after the other, and check after each activation, until you find the one makes the problem.
2. Too many data is being saved at one time. It can be too many variations or too many custom fields. This can be fixed by changing some PHP settings. Please have a look [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/problems-with-large-amounts-of-data-not-saving-variations-rates-etc/) especially under [the WPEngine note](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/problems-with-large-amounts-of-data-not-saving-variations-rates-etc/), and also check [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-max-submit-protect/).